# Counting all possibilities that contain a substring

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many strings are there of seven lowercase letters that have the substring tr in them?

So I am having a little problem with this question, I know that the total number of combinations is $26^6$ but there is double counting on some of the combinations.

For example, when you have a case that contains multiples 'tr' then it will be counted multiple times depending on the location of tr, even though its the same string.

t r t r t r a

Any advice on what to subtract to remove this double counting?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Better to count the number of ways to not get an instance of "tr," and then subtract that from $26^7$. (The total strings is $26^7$, not $26^6.)$.

Comment: I suggest two recurrences for strings not containing TR ending in T and not ending in T, solving these, and compute the value for length n=7.

Comment: But 'tr' is a substring that must stay together, meaning you can consider it as one object. So instead of having 7 spaces to fill you are only filling 5 then the substring takes up the other two as one making 6. Or did i do that totally wrong?

Comment: Because these parameters are very reasonable inclusion-exclusion will also work here. Apply stars-and-bars when you count the configurations containg $q$ copies of the string TR.

Comment: Never used stars-and-bars before but something like this?                                ★ |★ ★ ★ ★ ★   -   ★ |★ |★ ★ ★ ★     -   ★ ★ |★ |★ ★ ★    -   ★ ★ ★ |★ |★ ★    -    ★ ★ ★ ★ |★ |★    -   ★ ★ ★ ★ ★ |★       So there are 6 different spots the 'tr' can go and then the other spots should not contain 'tr' so remove 2 letters from the 5 spots. Then the final equation would be 26^6 - 6 x 2^5?

Comment: @Anon Did you find a combinatorics solution? Tad's solution is beautiful but I'm looking for something for a high school student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of strings of length $n$ with *no* tr's.  An $(n-1)$-long string can be extended in $26$ ways unless it ends in "t", in which case it can only be extended in $25$ ways.  So
$$a_n= 26a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}$$
for $n\ge2$; the initial conditions are $a_0=1$ and $a_1=26$.

You can give a formula for $a_n$, but to compute $a_7$ it suffices to run out the recurrence.  The final answer is $26^7-a_7 = 71,112,600$.

In case there's doubt, another way to verify the recurrence is to write down the $26\times26$ transition matrix for letters. All of the entries are $1$'s except for a single $0$ off the diagonal (corresponding to the prohibited tr).  The characteristic polynomial is computed to be $z^{24}(z^2-26z+1)$.

Comment: Thank you this helped a ton!

Comment: Does it extend to string of length more than 2? I'm working on a similar problem, but the substring is arbitrary. I write some script and found that $a_n = 26a_{n-1} - a_{n-2} - a_{n-3} - \ldots$ doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I get it now. Should be $a_n = 26a_{n-1} - a_{n-ss}$, where $ss$ is the length of the substring.

Comment: For general substrings, a good approach is to let $a_{n,k}$ be the number of strings of length n ending in the k-long prefix of the given substring, then write down a recurrence (the answer depends on how the substring overlaps with shifts of itself, so different substrings even of the same length can give different answers.)

Comment: @Tad Yes I've just bumped into the overlap! Is there any intuition for the fact that the number of strings containing `tt` is less than the number of strings containing `tr`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two  possible solutions here, one using  recurrences and the
other one using PIE.

**Recurrence.**

The recurrences use two  sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ which count
strings not containing the two-character pattern that end in the first
character of the pattern and that do not. This gives

$$a_1 = 1 \quad\text{and}\quad b_1 = 25$$
and for $n\gt 1$
$$a_n = a_{n-1} + b_{n-1}
\quad\text{and}\quad
b_n = 24a_{n-1} + 25b_{n-1}.$$

These recurrences produce for $1\le n\le 7$ the sequence of sums
$\{a_n+b_n\}$ which is
$$26, 675, 17524, 454949, 11811150, 306634951, 7960697576,\ldots$$
so that the answer to the problem is
(count of no ocurrences)
$$7960697576.$$

**Inclusion-Exclusion.**

Let  $M_{\ge  q}$  be the  set  of  strings  containing at  least  $q$
ocurrences of  the two-character pattern  and let $M_{=q}$ be  the set
containing   exactly  $q$   ocurrences  of   the  pattern.    Then  by
inclusion-exclusion we have

$$|M_{=0}| = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
(-1)^k |M_{\ge k}|.$$

Note however that
$$|M_{\ge k}| = 26^{n-2k} {n-2k + k\choose k}
= 26^{n-2k} {n-k\choose k}.$$

This is because when we have $k$ copies of the pattern there are $n-2k$ freely choosable letters that remain. Hence we have a total of $n-2k+k=n-k$ items to permute. We then choose the $k$ locations of the patterns among the $n-k$ items.

This gives the formula
$$|M_{=0}| = 
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^k \times
26^{n-2k} \times {n-k\choose k}.$$

```
a :=
proc(n)
    option remember;

    if n=1 then return 1 fi;

    a(n-1)+b(n-1);
end;


b :=
proc(n)
    option remember;

    if n=1 then return 25 fi;

    24*a(n-1)+25*b(n-1);
end;

ex_pie :=
proc(n)
    option remember;

    add((-1)^q*26^(n-2*q)*binomial(n-q,q),
        q=0..floor(n/2));
end;
```

**Proof that the two answers are the same.**

Introduce the generating functions
$$A(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} a_n z^n
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} b_n z^n.$$

Observe that the correct intial value pair is
$a_0 = 0$ and $b_0 = 1.$

Multiply the two recurrences by $z^n$ and sum over $n\ge 1$
to get
$$A(z) - 0 = z A(z) + z B(z)
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) - 1 = 24 z A(z) + 25 z B(z).$$

Solve these two obtain
$$A(z) = \frac{z}{z^2-26z+1}
\quad\text{and}\quad
B(z) = \frac{1-z}{z^2-26z+1}.$$

This yields the following generating function $G(z)$ for 
$\{a_n+b_n\}:$
$$G(z) = \frac{1}{z^2-26z+1}.$$

On the other hand we have
$$G(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0} z^n
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
26^{n-2k} (-1)^k {n-k\choose k}\right).$$

This is
$$\sum_{k\ge 0} 26^{-2k} (-1)^k
\sum_{n\ge 2k} 26^n z^n {n-k\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 0} 26^{-2k} (-1)^k \sum_{n\ge 0} 26^{n+2k} 
z^{n+2k} {n+2k-k\choose k}
\\ = \sum_{k\ge 0} z^{2k} (-1)^k
\sum_{n\ge 0} 26^n z^{n} {n+k\choose k}
= \sum_{k\ge 0} z^{2k} (-1)^k \frac{1}{(1-26z)^{k+1}}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-26z}
\sum_{k\ge 0} z^{2k} (-1)^k \frac{1}{(1-26z)^{k}}
= \frac{1}{1-26z} \frac{1}{1+z^2/(1-26z)}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-26z+z^2}.$$

This establishes the equality of the generating functions which was to
be shown.

**Closed form and OEIS entry.**

The roots of the denominator of the generating function are
$$\rho_{1,2} = 13 \pm 2\sqrt{42}.$$
Writing
$$\frac{1}{1-26z+z^2}
= \frac{1}{(z-\rho_1)(z-\rho_2)}
= \frac{1}{\rho_1-\rho_2}
\left(\frac{1}{z-\rho_1}-\frac{1}{z-\rho_2}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{42}}
\left(\frac{1}{\rho_1}\frac{1}{z/\rho_1-1}
-\frac{1}{\rho_2}\frac{1}{z/\rho_2-1}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{4\sqrt{42}}
\left(-\frac{1}{\rho_1}\frac{1}{1-z/\rho_1}
+\frac{1}{\rho_2}\frac{1}{1-z/\rho_2}\right).$$

We now extract coefficients to get
$$[z^n] G(z) =
\frac{1}{4\sqrt{42}}
\left(\rho_2^{-n-1}-\rho_1^{-n-1}\right).$$

Since $\rho_1\rho_2 = 1$ this finally becomes
$$[z^n] G(z) =
\frac{1}{4\sqrt{42}}
\left(\rho_1^{n+1}-\rho_2^{n+1}\right)$$

which is the sequence
$$26, 675, 17524, 454949, 11811150, 306634951, 7960697576,
\\ 206671502025, 5365498355074, 139296285729899, \ldots$$

This is [OEIS  A097309](https://oeis.org/A097309) which has additional
material and  where in fact  we find a  copy of the  problem statement
that initiated this thread.

**Alternative derivation of the closed form of $G(z).$**

This uses the following integral representation.
$${n-k\choose k}
= \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^{n-k}}{w^{k+1}} \; dw.$$

This gives for the inner sum
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^n}{w}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
26^{n-2k} (-1)^k \frac{1}{(1+w)^k w^k}\right) \; dw.$$

Note that the defining integral is zero when 
$\lfloor n/2\rfloor \lt k \le n,$ so this is in fact
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^n}{w}
\left(\sum_{k=0}^n
26^{n-2k} (-1)^k \frac{1}{(1+w)^k w^k}\right) \; dw.$$

Simplifying we obtain
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(1+w)^n}{w} 26^n
\frac{(-1)^{n+1}/26^{2(n+1)}/(1+w)^{n+1}/w^{n+1}-1}
{(-1)/26^2/(1+w)/w-1} \; dw$$
or
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
(1+w)^{n+1} 26^n
\frac{(-1)^{n+1}/26^{2(n+1)}/(1+w)^{n+1}/w^{n+1}-1}
{(-1)/26^2-w(w+1)} \; dw$$

The difference  from the geometric  series contributes two  terms, the
second of which has no poles inside the contour, leaving just

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon}
\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{26^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{w^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(-1)/26^2-w(w+1)} \; dw.$$

It follows that
$$G(z) = \sum_{n\ge 0}
z^n [w^n] \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{26^{n+2}}
\frac{1}{(-1)/26^2-w(w+1)}.$$

What  we have  here is  an *annihilated  coefficient  extractor* which
simplifies as follows.
$$\frac{-1}{26^2} \sum_{n\ge 0}
(-z/26)^n [w^n] \frac{1}{(-1)/26^2-w(w+1)}
\\ = \frac{-1}{26^2} 
\frac{1}{(-1)/26^2+z/26(-z/26+1)}
= -\frac{1}{-1+z(-z+26)}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-26z+z^2}.$$

This concludes the argument.

There is another *annihilated coefficient extractor* at this
[MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/894240/).

Comment: This is amazing, but I am confused because for a string of length 1 there should be 0 strings that contain 'tr' then strings of length 2 should only contain 1 ('tr') then Strings of length 3 should be 52 i believe (t,r,26)or(26,t,r) but you came up with 26,675,172554?

Comment: Oh wow never mind that is how many strings that don't contain the 'tr' so for 7 characters 26^7 - 7960697576 = 71,112,600.

Comment: Seriously thank you so much for taking all this time to solve this, you helped me actually understand where the numbers were coming from.