# An identity involving binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the following identity
$$\displaystyle \sum_{i+j=m}\frac{(n-1) \binom{ai+n-1}{i} \binom{aj+1}{j}}{(ai+n-1)(aj+1)} =  \frac{n\binom{am+n}{m}}{am+n}$$
where $i = 0,1,\cdots,m$ and $m, n$ are positive integers and $a$ is a positive integer or even a fraction.

One complete proof can be found in that famous book "Concrete Mathematics" by
Ronald L. Graham, Donald E. Knuth, and Oren Patashnik  which is widely used as a textbook in many computer science departments.

Another complete proof can be found in the book written by Egorychev which is directly using the inversion rule of residue, see page 49 in the book "Integral representation and the computation of combinatorial sums". If you are reading that book, keep in mind that the index under $\sum$ can be extended to infinity because the contour integral has no pole when $k>n$.

Comment: Please don't destroy your question.  Others may find it and its answer useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a nice example to apply the *inversion rule* of formal power series stated as rule 4 in G.P. Egorychevs *[Integral Representations  and the Computation of Combinatorial Sums](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821845128)* section 1.2.2.

I think it's worthwhile to present a complete proof. Here we use the *[coefficient of](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9402216)* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ in a formal power series. We show

> The following is valid for $m,n\geq 1$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$ appropriate
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{i+j=m}\atop{i,j\geq 0}}&\frac{n-1}{ai+n-1}\binom{ai+n-1}{i}\frac{1}{aj+1}\binom{aj+1}{j}
> =\frac{n}{am+n}\binom{am+n}{m}
> \end{align*}

$$ $$

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{i+j=m}\atop{i,j\geq 0}}&\frac{n-1}{ai+n-1}\binom{ai+n-1}{i}\frac{1}{aj+1}\binom{aj+1}{j}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^m\frac{n-1}{ai+n-1}\binom{ai+n-1}{i}\frac{1}{am-ai+1}\binom{am-ai+1}{m-i}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\left\{\binom{ai+n-1}{i}-a\binom{ai+n-2}{i-1}\right\}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\left\{\binom{am-ai+1}{m-i}-a\binom{am-ai}{m-i-1}\right\}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left([z^i](1+z)^{ai+n-1}-a[z^{i-1}](1+z)^{ai+n-2}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\left([w^{m-i}](1+w)^{a(m-i)+1}-a[w^{m-i-1}](1+w)^{a(m-i)}\right)\\
> &=[w^m](1+w)^{am}(1+w-aw)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{w}{(1+w)^a}\right)^i[z^i](1+z)^{n-2}(1+z-az)(1+z)^{ai}\tag{2}\\
> &=[w^m](1+w)^{am}(1+w-aw)\left.\left((1+z)^{n-1}\right)\right|_{z=w}\tag{3}\\
> &=[w^m](1+w)^{am+n}-a[w^{m-1}](1+w)^{am+n-1}\\
> &=\binom{am+n}{m}-a\binom{am+n-1}{m-1}\\
> &=\frac{n}{am+n}\binom{am+n}{m}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the identity $$\frac{q}{pk+q}\binom{pk+q}{k}=\binom{pk+q}{k}-p\binom{pk+q-1}{k-1}$$ We also set the upper limit of the sum to $\infty$ without changing anything since we are only adding zero.
- In (2) we rearrange the sum, use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and the rule $[z^{n-k}]A(z)=[z^n]z^kA(z)$.
- In (3) we use the *inversion rule*

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^\infty w^i [z^i]A(z)f^i(z)=\left.\left(A(z)\frac{f(z)}{f(z)-zf^{\prime}(z)}\right)\right|_{z=g(w)}
\end{align*}
with $g(w)$ the inverse of $w=\frac{z}{g(z)}$. We get from (2)
\begin{align*}
A(z)&=(1+z)^{n-2}(1+z-az)\\
f(z)&=(1+z)^a
\end{align*}
and obtain
\begin{align*}
A(z)\frac{f(z)}{f(z)-zf^{\prime}(z)}&=(1+z)^{n-2}(1+z-az)\frac{(1+z)^a}{(1+z)^a-az(a+z)^{a-1}}\\
&=(1+z)^{n-1}
\end{align*}
Since $w=\frac{z}{f(z)}=\frac{z}{(1+z)^a}$ we apply in (3) the substitution $z=w$.

Comment: (+1). Upvoted. I congratulate you on presenting this difficult material from the canonical text. I had not used the inversion rule because the proof of this rule as found in the book requires more machinery than what can be presented in a MSE post. Reading your computation I have now found a rigorous proof of these identities by a simple substitution which you may find above. It relies on formal power series identities only and makes no assumptions about the trajectories of the poles of a bivariate complex function.

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Thanks for your nice comment and +1 for your updated answer. I've already upvoted your other answer some days before. Btw, I appreciate your Wikipedia articles. The last one about *[Egorychevs Method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egorychev_method)* with this nice ref to your example collection is worth a detailed reading! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Apparently G. P. Egorychev does not have a biographical entry in English at Wikipedia. Do you know if his biography is somewhere on the internet in a major European language and preferably under the license that Wikipedia uses?

Comment: @MarkoRiedel: Regrettably I can't provide you with helpful information. In the course of his 70th birthday in 2008, Springer published *[Advances in Combinatorial Mathematics](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642035616)* which contains contributions in honor of Egorychev. Maybe you can retrieve information about him from one of the contributors.If so, I'm also keen to get some information about his life. Best regards,

Comment: @MarkusScheuer  there is a $n$ missing at the RHS numerator of the starting identity, same at the numerator of the very last one (it should be as in the first dot of the comment), but otherwise the  demonstration is correct and very interesting as for the method applied. And, concerning the definition field, actually $a$ could be also complex, and same $n$ (apart $1$), while $m$ can be also $0$ (when $n \ne 0,1$).

Comment: @GCab: Good to see the  methods are useful for you and thanks for the good review! :-) Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to the second sum that was posted which does indeed use exactly the same method as the first and being more compact is easier to read and understand.

Suppose we seek to verify that

$$\sum_{k=0}^m \frac{q}{pk+q}
{pk+q\choose k} {pm-pk\choose m-k} = {mp+q\choose m}.$$

Observe that

$${pk+q\choose k} = \frac{pk+q}{k} {pk+q-1\choose k-1}$$

so that
$${pk+q\choose k} - p {pk+q-1\choose k-1}
= \frac{q}{k} {pk+q-1\choose k-1}
= \frac{q}{pk+q} {pk+q\choose k}.$$

This yields two pieces for the sum, call them $S_1$

$$\sum_{k=0}^m {pk+q\choose k} {pm-pk\choose m-k}$$

and $S_2$

$$- p \sum_{k=0}^m {pk+q-1\choose k-1} {pm-pk\choose m-k}.$$

For $S_1$ introduce the integrals

$${pk+q\choose k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma} 
\frac{(1+z)^{pk+q}}{z^{k+1}} 
\; dz$$

and

$${pm-pk\choose m-k} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm-pk}}{w^{m-k+1}} 
\; dw.$$

The second  one controls the range of the sum because the pole at  zero vanishes when $k\gt m$ so we may extend  $k$ to infinity,
getting for the sum

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm}}{w^{m+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma} 
\frac{(1+z)^{q}}{z}
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{w^k}{z^k} \frac{(1+z)^{pk}}{(1+w)^{pk}}
\; dz\; dw
\\ =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm}}{w^{m+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma} 
\frac{(1+z)^{q}}{z}
\frac{1}{1-w(1+z)^p/z/(1+w)^p}
\; dz\; dw 
\\ =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm+p}}{w^{m+1}} 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma} 
(1+z)^{q}
\frac{1}{z(1+w)^p-w(1+z)^p}
\; dz\; dw.$$

Suppose $|\epsilon| < |\gamma|$ which makes 
$\left|\frac{w(1+z)^p}{z(1+w)^p}\right| < 1$ so that we have convergence of the geometric series and suppose we  can prove that $z=w$  is the only pole  inside the contour
and it is simple. We have

$$\left((1+w)^p z - w(1+z)^p\right)'
= (1+w)^p - pw(1+z)^{p-1} = (1+w)^{p-1}(1+w-wp).$$

We can choose $|\epsilon|$ small enough such that $|1+w-wp| >0$, so the pole is order 1, which yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm+p}}{w^{m+1}} 
(1+w)^q \frac{1}{(1+w)^{p-1}} \frac{1}{1+w-pw}
\; dw
\\ = 
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm+q+1}}{w^{m+1}} 
\frac{1}{1+w-pw}
\; dw.$$

Following exactly the same procedure we obtain for $S_2$

$$-p \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm+q}}{w^{m}} 
\frac{1}{1+w-pw}
\; dw.$$

Adding these two pieces now yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm+q}}{w^{m}} 
\left(\frac{1+w}{w} - p\right)
\frac{1}{1+w-pw}
\; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm+q}}{w^{m+1}} 
\; dw
\\ = {pm+q\choose m}.$$

**Remark Mon Jan 25 2016.**

An alternate proof which is completely rigorous and does not depend on
assumptions about  the poles of a bivariate  complex function proceeds
from the integral

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm}}{w^{m+1}} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{w^k}{(1+w)^{pk}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\gamma} 
\frac{(1+z)^{q}}{z^{k+1}}
(1+z)^{pk}
\; dz\; dw$$

Now put

$$u = \frac{z}{(1+z)^p}
\quad\text{and introduce}\quad
g(u) = z.$$

We then have
$$du = 
\left(\frac{1}{(1+z)^p} - p\frac{z}{(1+z)^{p+1}}\right) \; dz
= \left(\frac{u}{g(u)} - \frac{pu}{1+g(u)}\right) \; dz$$

and
$$dz  = \frac{1}{u}\frac{g(u) (1+g(u))}{1 + g(u) - p g(u)} \; du.$$

This yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm}}{w^{m+1}} 
\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{w^k}{(1+w)^{pk}}
\\ \times \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|u|=\gamma} 
\frac{1}{g(u) u^{k}} (1+g(u))^q 
\frac{1}{u}\frac{g(u) (1+g(u))}{1 + g(u) - p g(u)}
\; du\; dw$$

or
$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm}}{w^{m+1}} 
\left.(1+g(u))^q 
\frac{1+g(u)}{1 + g(u) - p g(u)}
\right|_{u=w/(1+w)^p} \; dw.$$

Now observe that $g(w/(1+w)^p) = w$ by definition so we get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm}}{w^{m+1}} 
(1+w)^q 
\frac{1+w}{1 + w - p w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|w|=\epsilon} 
\frac{(1+w)^{pm+q+1}}{w^{m+1}} 
\frac{1}{1 + w - p w} \; dw.$$

This is exactly the same as before and the rest of the proof continues
unchanged.

What we have used here is the technique of *annihilated coefficient
extractors* of which there are several more examples at this [MSE link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184319/)  and at  this [MSE
link  II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213727/)  and  also
here             at             this             [MSE             link
III](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130883/).

Answer (score -1):

Follow the same reasoning when proving this identity, 
$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^m\frac{q }{pi+q}\binom{pi+q}{i} \binom{pm-pi}{m-i} = \binom{mp+q}{m}$$
You can just read the book yourself. Too difficult to post the book here!

it can be proved using the inversion rule of residue, see page 49 Integral representation and the computation of combinatorial sums