# Fibonacci numbers of higher order

Tags: combinatorics

Which short closed-form formulas for the Fibonacci numbers of higher order $F(m;n)$ ([Wikipedia: Generalizations of Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Fibonacci_numbers_of_higher_order)), or of its shifted form $F(m;n+m-1)$, are there?

I already found two formulas. I found them with help of Math.StackExchange (see [Math.StackExchange: Simplifying my sum which contains binomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626949/simplifying-my-sum-which-contains-binomials)).

Answer (score 0):

A linear recurrence relation with $n$ terms with constant factors has a closd form solution in the form of $n$ exponential functions (similar to what happens with differential equation). So, write it down as

$$a_{n}-a_{n-1}\ldots-a_{n-k}=0$$
write $a_{n}=A q^n$, and solve the characteristic equation for all possible $q$ (the solution is then a superposition of these that matches the initial terms).

Comment: A closed-form expression for the number $F(m;n)$ or $F(m;n+m-1)$ in dependence of $m$ and $n$ is meant, not a generating function for all this numbers.

Comment: $a_{n}=Aq^n$ means $A$ will be eliminated. Therefore $A$ is not needed. Have I understood your comment correctly?

Comment: True, not needed to get $q$ - like for all homogeneous linear equations, scaling a solution gives another solution.