# A sum of Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, asymptotics, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

Find a formula (either exact or asymptotic in $N$) for $S(N)$, where
\begin{equation}
S(N) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty \sum_{k=N}^n \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{k-j} (1+j)^n \frac{t^n}{n!}.
\end{equation}
Here $N\geq 1$, $\binom{k}{j}$ is the combinatorial symbol, and $t$ is a formal parameter.

Note: perhaps it is useful to recall the Stirling numbers of the second kind, 
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
n \\ k 
\end{array} \right\} = \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{k-j} j^n,
\end{equation}
and their generating function 
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left\{ \begin{array}{c}
n \\ k 
\end{array} \right\} \frac{x^n}{n!} = \frac{(e^x-1)^k}{k!}.
\end{equation}

*I appreciate comments regarding special functions, asymptotic techniques, or references that could be useful to solve this problem.*

Comment: This could be a start:

\begin{align}
S(N) &= \sum_{n=N}^\infty \sum_{k=N}^n \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{k-j} (1+j)^n \frac{t^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=N}^\infty \sum_{k=N}^n \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{k-j} \sum_{l=0}^n\binom nlj^l \frac{t^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum_{n=N}^\infty \sum_{k=N}^n  \sum_{l=0}^n\binom nl\frac{t^n}{n!}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j} (-1)^{k-j}j^l \\
&=\sum_{n=N}^\infty \sum_{k=N}^n  \sum_{l=0}^n\binom nl\frac{t^n}{n!}k!\left\{l\atop k\right\}\\
\end{align}

Comment: @joriki, this is certainly useful. The sum of the Stirling numbers weighted with $k!$ look the the ordered Bell numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_Bell_number

Comment: @joriki Generating functions to the rescue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we seek to evaluate

$$S(N) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty
\sum_{k=N}^n \sum_{j=0}^k {k\choose j} (-1)^{k-j} 
(1+j)^n \frac{t^n}{n!}.$$

This is

$$S(N) = \sum_{n=N}^\infty  \frac{t^n}{n!}
\sum_{k=N}^n \sum_{j=0}^k {k\choose j} (-1)^{k-j} 
(1+j)^n.$$

Now introduce

$$(1+j)^n =
\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \exp((1+j)z) \; dz.$$

We thus get for the inner sum

$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{1}{z^{n+1}} 
\sum_{j=0}^k {k\choose j} (-1)^{k-j} 
\exp((1+j)z) \; dz
\\ = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(z)}{z^{n+1}} 
(\exp(z)-1)^k\; dz.$$

Substitute this into the middle sum to get

$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(z)}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{n+1} - (\exp(z)-1)^N}{\exp(z)-2}
\; dz.$$

Now since  $\exp(z)-1$ starts at $z$  the first term drops  out and we
get

$$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(z)}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^N}{2-\exp(z)}
\; dz.$$

We thus get for the remaining sum

$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{t^n}{n!} \frac{n!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(z)}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^N}{2-\exp(z)}
\; dz.$$

Finally note  that $(\exp(z)-1)^N$ starts  at $z^N$ so we  may lower
the initial value of the remaining summation to zero, getting

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} \frac{\exp(z)}{z^{n+1}} 
\frac{(\exp(z)-1)^N}{2-\exp(z)}
\; dz.$$

What  we have  here is  an *annihilated  coefficient extractor*  which
finally yields

$$\frac{\exp(t)}{2-\exp(t)} (\exp(t)-1)^N.$$

Now for  the exponential growth rate  of the coefficients on  $t^n$ we
get the distance to the nearest  singularity which is $\log 2.$ So the
radius of convergence of this sum is $|t|<\log 2.$

**Observation.** Having reached the end of this computation we see that we didn't need to substitute the variable in the integral, which means we could have used the coefficient extractor notation $[z^n]$ throughout. This does not affect the semantics of the computation.

**Remark.**  There are several  more examples of the  technique of
*annihilated    coefficient   extractors*    at    this   [MSE    link
I](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184319/)  and at  this [MSE
link  II](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1213727/)  and  also
here             at             this             [MSE             link
III](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130883/).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I appreciate very much your detailed answer and the links, thanks. By the way, I came up with this type of sum since I am trying to evaluate the error term in a numerical method (of order $N$) I am working at.